# jQuery Mobile: reload button control after ajax load()

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile, refresh

How can I re-style (jQuery Mobile like) a `<button type="submit" />` which is ajax-loaded inside a div as:

```
$("#containerDiv").load("pageWhichContainsTheButton.html");
```

The button shows up as simple html button.

I read that other components have their own re-rendering functions: .listview() and so on.

Is there a .button() function or others I may use?

I don't want to manually apply "mobile-style" classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to tell JQM to apply it's magic-styling, try this after the load is successfull:

```
$("#containerDiv button").trigger("create");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: however, the .button() function does exist, too! :)

Comment: yes it does, since it's a JQM widget, you can call all of them that way as well - the trigger thought helps in case you have multiple different widgets...